# Span middle align not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to design a mobile website. Need to get ABC middle vertically. I followed other SO questions reg how to get SPAN text vertically middle. But here its not working. I have included the jsfiddle. **http://jsfiddle.net/3tdYT/**   I am not sure what I am missing out.

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/72x38"></div>
            <div id="menu">a</div>
            <div id="title-wrapper"><div id="title"><span id="screen-title">ABC</span></div></div>

        </div>
        <div id="company-name">CCCCCC</div>     
    </div>



 * {    margin:0; padding:0}

#header{
    height:53px;
    padding:0;
}
        #logo{  
            float:left; 
            background: #ffffff;
            padding:5px;
        }
        #title{
            text-align:center;
            height:100%;                
            margin:0 auto;

        }
        #title-wrapper{

            height:100%;
            background: #ff3eae;
        }
        #screen-title{
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;

        }
        #menu{
            width:20%;
            height:100%;
            float:right;
            padding:0;
            background: #E23222;
        }
#company-name{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background: darkblue;
    clear:left;
    padding:0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
#main {width:240px}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn `#title`'s display into a `table` and `#screen-title`'s display into a `table-cell`:

```
/* ... */

    #title{
        display: table;
        height:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

/* ... */

    #screen-title{
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XMcCR/3/

But notice that there are lots of possibilitis to vertically center some text with css, each with its own specific disadvantages. This is just one possibility. Simply check some of the results of a quick Google search for "vertically center css". It almost appears to be some kind of own scientific field.

Comment: thanks. It works. In my case, I'm having a div containing a span & a button. The span containing a checkbox & a label. Button is bigger & I want to vertically middle align the span.

Comment: @AdarshSinghal: Please post a new question for that if you don't find an answer on your own.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to set a static height and width for it.
That should work. have a try)

```
    #screen-title{
            display: table-cell;
            height: 50px;
            width: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: Xpx` where X is a suitable value to get the effect you want (typically the same as the height of the element)

Comment: An example of Kolink's method: http://jsfiddle.net/3tdYT/1/. It's not ideal since you have to know the explicit height, but it'll do the trick.